# Can't convert URL into hyperlink to store in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

Sorry to be back two days in a row.  I spent the whole day yesterday reading on this site and others and I'm just stuck.  The only thing I found close was for C++.  I'm building a data base for my DVDs and Movies so I and my friends can search by Title, Actors, etc. With help here yesterday, I was able to get a data entry form working.  One of the fields is a hyperlink to IMDB for info about the movie.  I want to just be able to paste the URL into the form but have it stored as a full hyperlink in MySQL.  When it comes up in the results pages it just appears as a link I can click on and go to the IMDB page.

This is what I've come up with so far.  I get a syntax error if I include the "target="_blank"> but if I take that out there's no syntax error but I get the "Error X" with no error code and no entry into the database.  Is there any way I can get this to work?  Thanks in advance.

```
    //  Make link info into hyperlink for database

        $url = ('$_POST[link]');
    $f_link = "<a href= " . $url . "target="_blank">IMDB Movie Page</a>";

    //  Write data to table.    

    $sql="INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, BitRate, link)
        VALUES      ('$_POST[Movies]','$_POST[Rating]','$_POST[Genre]','$_POST[Year]','$_POST[Actors]','$_POST[    Time]','$_POST[Notes]','$_POST[Viewed]','$_POST[BitRate]', $f_link)";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: X ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your question about the quotes:
consider the following sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table1 where id = god";
```

mysql interpret got as some thing else than a string ('god' is different from got).

therefore you should type

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table1 where id = 'god'";
```

or

```
$value = 'god';
$sql = "SELECT * from table1 where id = '{$value}'";
```

or

```
$value = 'god';
$sql = "SELECT * from table1 where id = '" .  $value . "'";
```

Note: in case the value is a Numeric (flaot, integer, ... ), then you don't neet the quote

```
$value = 12334;
$sql = "SELECT * from table1 where id = {$god}";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me.  I don't fully get it but it helps.  I'll be coming back here and re-reading this until I commit it to memory.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes when you want to include them inside a quoted string.

```
$f_link = "<a href= " . $url . " target=\"_blank\">IMDB Movie Page</a>";
```

but you should also have quote around the URL

```
$f_link = "<a href=\"" . $url . "\" target=\"_blank\">IMDB Movie Page</a>";
```

Using single quotes to enclose makes it easier,

```
$f_link = '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">IMDB Movie Page</a>';
```

but bear in mind PHP doesn't parse the contents in this instance, which isn't a problem in that line because you've concatenated $url, which is the cleaner way.

Also note you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection be allowing those $_POSTs to be directly inserted into a SQL command.

Comment: Thanks popnoodles.  I see you edited something after I tried it.  Unfortunately when I tried it there was syntax errors that I couldn't find and correct.  Fortunately for me then next comment worked after I found one simple error.  As I said above, I do have to learn about this SQL injection.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you store the plain `$url` in the database without the HTML. If you later want to change your link you would have to work out how to update all your records... If you switch your code to just store the URL without adding HTML around it, it will fix the error (which is unescaped quoted).

When you retrieve the URL from the database, you can wrap it with your HTML and avoid that pain.

You are doing great to get started in just a couple of days with this - but you may need to have a think about SQL injection as even if you don't think someone will deliberately attack your page, you could accidentally cause problems if you don't parametrise your SQL - for example if someone accidentally types a `'` into the form.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  I really wish I was doing as well as you think.  A lot of what you said went right over my head.  I have done a little reading on SQL Injection, which was a new term for me.  Fortunately there is nothing in the database that you can't find on the web so an attack to download the info won't get anyone anything.  I'll keep reading and learning and I do appreciate the help.

Comment: No problems... the worst case scenario would be someone entering ... `'); DROP TABLE Movies;` into the link input - this would lose you all your data!

Comment: Steve, I'm not just wet behind the ears, I have an ocean there.  I never thought about someone messing with me.  I had the password included in the PHP page because I knew no one could see it.  But then it hit me that if anyone found the HTML page for the form they could at least put anything they wanted into the table and maybe worse.  So I added a password field to the form and now I have to enter it each time I ad a record.  Maybe not the best but a step in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry - it will become second nature before long :)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: Thanks to your warning and another one on here I figured out how to save my database from my server to my computer for a back up.  You've been great!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code through:

```
$url = ($_POST['link']);
$f_link = "<a href= \" {$url}\" target=\"_blank\">IMDB Movie Page</a>";

//  Write data to table.    

$sql="INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, BitRate, link)
    VALUES
    ('"  . $_POST['Movies'] ."', '" . $_POST['Rating'] . "', '" . $_POST['Genre'] . "', '" . $_POST['Year']" . ', '" . $_POST['Actors'] ."', '" . $_POST['Time'] . "', '" . $_POST['Notes'] . "','" . $_POST['Viewed'] . "','" . $_POST['BitRate'] . "', '{$f_link}' )";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
     die('Error: X ' . mysql_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Ulrich, you were a life saver.  It didn't work at first but that was a simple problem after ['Year'] that I'm sure was just typing fast.  If I can ask, are all the . "' to do with the SQL Injection?  If not is there somewhere I can read up on why this worked when my code didn't?  Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Based on your observation and someone else I found out how to save my database from my server to my computer for a back up, just in case.  I searched for help on ( vs { vs [ but I found nothing.  Also for ' vs " and again nothing. But I'll look until I find somewhere that will give me a grasp of what to use where. Thanks.

Comment: Which client interface do you use to access your database? In case you use phpmyadmin or MySQL Workbench, they have Menu's option that let you export your whole database.

Comment: Actually the web server has a back up program that let me do it.  I do use PHP MyAdmin though.  I'll go take a look.  Thanks.